# Getting Error on Using JMockit: Could not initialize class mockit.coverage.Metrics

Tags: java, maven, jmockit, jmock

I am running a Jenkins job that build a package. However all the tests are failing with the following errors:

```
**Error Message** :
   Could not initialize class mockit.coverage.Metrics
**Stacktrace** :
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mockit.coverage.Metrics
```

Pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Assuming that you are packaging the app (mvn clean install etc.), your test classes will not be in the classpath. Delete the <scope>test</scope> line.

Comment: Why should the scope:test deleted? It is a test dependency so this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using jmockit 1.24 (May 2016) and not the current version?  It's quite likely you have stumbled into some old bug long since fixed.  Upgrade.

http://jmockit.github.io/changes.html